# How to change stream in tweepy if hashtag changed?

Tags: python, queue, hashtag, tweepy

I have a situation where I'm starting tweepy streaming with default hashtag, than program receives a queue and changes hashtag, but my question is how to apply this new hashtag to already running tweepy streaming ?

To be more clear will give an example:

```
    hashtag = 'number_1'

    auth = t_auth()
    self.stream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth,CustomStreamListener())
    self.stream.filter(follow=None, track=[hashtag])
```

Ok, the code above will listen for the hashtag `'number_1'`, Now imagine that I received a queue with different hashtag:

```
    hashtag = 'Different_hashtag'
```

So how to make my `self.stream.filter(follow=None, track=[hashtag]` start listening for a new hashtag?

Comment: Have you tried to call `self.stream.disconnect()` and call `self.stream.filter(follow=None, track=[hashtag])` again? Seems like it's the only way.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but, where should I put it? because once I call `stream.filter()` it blocks everything, and the code after will not be executed.

Comment: Somewhere in your `CustomStreamListener` I think. Choose appropriate method and override it: see https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py#L20. Seems like it should be `on_status` or `on_data`.

Answer (score 2):

As @alecxe stated in the comments, you can disconnect the stream from one of the callback methods, either by calling `stream.disconnect()`, or returning `False`

Another option is to call `stream.filter` with `async=True`. This will listen for Tweets asynchronously, allowing you to call `stream.disconnect()` and `stream.filter()` from your main code when you receive a different hashtag.